# Is there anyway to Like a Facebook Page from within the website, or with the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm just wondering if there is anyway to have the like-page correspond to the `Facebook Page` rather than the website. My organization mirrors it's efforts inside of Facebook, and so I don't see any reason to even make Facebook aware of the website.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Can you give us an example of what you want to do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**SURE!**

The Facebook Like Plugin make it very simple to Like your Facebook Page from almost anywhere:

> **Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?**
>   Yes. Simply specify the URL of your
>   Facebook page in the `href` parameter
>   of the button.

[Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).